# A simple thing to ask on the CSS margin-left:auto in my case

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple nested `<div>` layout:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="options">
        <a href="#">option 1</a> |
        <a href="#">option 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I applied a very simple **CSS** :

```
#main{
  height:50px;
  background-color: #cc00ff 
}

/*here is the thing confused me*/
#options{
  margin-left:auto;
  width: 8em;
}
```

You can run it on [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jqrE6/4/). Everything works fine.  **But there is one little thing confused me**: which is, **why** the **CSS** code :

```
#options{
  margin-left:auto;
  width: 8em;
}
```

makes the **options** `<div>` to be located to the **right side** of the **main** `<div>` ? Anyone can explain to me the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you have set an auto margin on one side, which means it will just fill the space given it. I suppose this is the same sort of result as applying a float of right, but without any impact on document flow. It basically works out the automatic margin by removing the width left after the width of the contained elements.

If you wanted it centered you'd need to add an auto margin to both, with fills both sides of the parent with the width left over equally.

Comment: do you mean if I do not specify maring-right but only margin-left, it will only fill the space to left, there will not be any space on right side unless I specify it ?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. If you give the element a width the margin will be the parent width minus the element width (and the same with a right margin I believe)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you put the  `margin-left:auto;` in the `option` DIV. The option div is gone to the right because of the  `margin-left`. It is already left aligned. If you want the `option` div in the center, just need to put the `margin:0 auto;`

Thanks,
Arun Krishnan

Comment: I have never said I want option div to be in the center... I feel strange when I read your reply. It's like I am asking one thing while you are talking about another thing.